# Where to find javascript code that is responsible for the created animation? - Webflow

Tags: javascript, webflow

I'm sure there are people here who work in webflow and have familiarized themselves with its code.

It's wonderful, but because of the Tram - extensive.

How do I find a piece of javascript code that is responsible for playing a particular animation? For example, for the trigger "Click"?

---

For example, an animation is played here by clicking on the input. It's Javascript. http://searchsearch.webflow.io/

But how do I find this piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a Webflow plan to be able to download the source code.
Also you can uncheck minify js at the bottom of the hosting section of your project setting (it will make the code a bit more readable).

When you have your javascript file downloaded you can search its content for Interactions 2.0

There you will have a json object that contain all the informations required for interactions to work.

Copy/paste this object in a json formatter for readability and you will have access to all these informations.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: I was once told that json itself does not create animations. Ostensibly this the usual exchange data.

The thing is that I would like to use certain animations for different objects. For example, create a button with a hover animation and use it on third-party services. 

Is that true? I won't be able to use a specific animation with a specific element outside of the webflow.js?

Comment: The json indeed is not creating the animation but it contains the informations which would be used by the interactions (animations) you defined in webflow. I'm a bit confused about what you are trying to achieve and what you mean by using on third-party services.

Comment: If JSON doesn't create animation, where is the code that creates it? 

Imagine that you want to share the created button on the codepen. And would you embed the entire webflow.js file? This is stupid, because it contains the entire database of cms and e-commerce.

Of course not, I would (and you would) insert only the piece of code that creates the animation you need. In my case - the animation for the buttons (guidance).

But how to find this code?